# Command Line Slicer OSX Terminal

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, slic3r, automation

What are the correct steps for slicing an .stl file with OSX Terminal. I have tried `cd` to the directory where the .stl file is and then `CuraEngine slice -s mesh_rotation_matrix=[[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]]" -l my3DP.stl -o my3DP.gcode`. Nothing happens when I run this sequence of commands. I also tried Slic3r but get a command not found error.

Comment: Found some info on and was able to pull up the help for slic3r. https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/issues/1259

Comment: With the following code I was almost able to do a command line slice with Cura. 'CuraEngine slice -v -j /Applications/3D\ Printing/Cura.app/Contents/Resources/share/cura/resources/definitions/fdmprinter.def.json -j /Applications/3D\ Printing/Cura.app/Contents/Resources/share/cura/resources/definitions/fdmextruder.def.json -l my3DP.stl  -o my3DP.gcode' I was only able to make it work after specifying a series of other settings that for some reason cura engine calls up even though I specified the def.json definitions.

Comment: These are all of the other settings I had to specify or else cura engine throws up errors and doesn't slice. '-s 'material_shrinkage_percentage'='100' -s 'adhesion_extruder_nr'='0' -s 'fill_perimeter_gaps'='false' -s 'filter_out_tiny_gaps'='true' -s 'speed_equalize_flow_enabled'='true' -s 'travel_compensate_overlapping_walls_0_enabled'='true' -s 'travel_compensate_overlapping_walls_x_enabled'='true' -s 'outer_inset_first'='false' -s 'wall_min_flow'='1' -s 'wall_min_flow_retract'='1''